# Calling a Python function by a dataframe column category

Tags: python, function

I am using the following function to compute a test for the Values column in `df`.
My goal is to able to perform the test for each Year and Category.

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_rel
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

def Compute(df, Values, popmean=58):
    test, pvalue = stats.ttest_1samp(Values, popmean, nan_policy='omit')
    return test, pvalue
```

Right now, if I call the function `Compute(df, Values, popmean=58)`,
it will perform the calculations for all values regardless of Year and Category.  Ultimately,I want a solution whereby the data is filtered for each Year and category for the test and then all results listed.

```
Year    Category Values
1990    Alpha   171
1990    Alpha   145
1990    Alpha   147
1995    Alpha   161
1995    Alpha   171
1995    Alpha   141
1990    Beta    115
1990    Beta    132
1990    Beta    146
1995    Beta    102
1995    Beta    97
1995    Beta    95
```

Comment: "I have a function "-  please show relevant code...

Comment: Are you looking for `df.groupby(['Year', 'Category']).mean()`?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and help. I updated the post with clear  details and the function I am using. So far, it works when I only calculate for all the values.  I want to use the function for each combination of Year and Category.